# Is there a function available in Kotlin language, which gets a string with XML and returning DOM?

Tags: xml, string, kotlin, parsing, dom

I having a task:

1. Get a string containing arbitrary XML
2. Parse it into a DOM

Is there any solution available for this task in Kotlin?

Comment: What platform you're targeting?

Comment: The Kotlin target platform is JVM.

Comment: Then you may use any XML parser defined in Java stdlib (see https://mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/)